# video streaming with ember.js using video.js

Tags: javascript, video, ember.js, video.js

I am trying to stream video using ember.js and video.js as a part of my practice projects

This is what I  have done so far:

component/video.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import videojs from 'videojs';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  player: videojs('example-video'),

  x: this.get("player").ready(function() {
    this.get("player").src({
    src: 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
    type: 'video/mp4'
    }).play();

  }),
});
```

template/component/video.hbs:

```
{{yield}}
```

template/component/video-play.hbs

```
<h1>play video</h1>
  <p>
      {{video}}
  </p>
```

route/video-play.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

});
```

I am kind of new to ember and trying to keep the app simple. However, upon inspection I get this error:

```
The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)
```

not quite sure what this error is and what causing this error

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: You can place `videojs` function call and its `ready` inside [`didInsertElement `](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/)hook method of `video` component.

Comment: I did that but its still giving me the same error

Comment: In alternative there is an existing ember library that allows the usage of video.js in ember, here is the link https://github.com/IvyApp/ivy-videojs

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to do this stand alone without ember. and then try it in ember that would be super helpful.

From their [setup document](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html) I can see we need video tag element and its elementId should be passed to `videojs`. I think you missed this step.

You can achieve this in by writing the below in `my-video` component hbs itself.

```
<video id="my-video">
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
</video>
```

You can mention `tagName` and `id` argument while including component

```
{{my-video tagName='video' id="my-video"}}
```

Also read [Component life cycles](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/)

Note: [Components](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/defining-a-component/) must have at least one dash in their name

Comment: Cool Thanks for the response, [link](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html) might be helpful, However, I have already tried using plain index.html to play around with video so wanted to jump to ember

Comment: `<video id=`example-video`> </video>` if  you got this inside component hbs then you will not receive  `The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)` error.